# How can I give a List of objects as parameter with MockMvcBuilder

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my Spring Boot project, i have a controller called AdminGameController which methods I want to test using Springs MockMvcBuilder. This works fine for methods which handles the GET request, but for the POST methods, a Game object is needed as parameter, see the handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/game/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdate(@Valid Game game,
                   BindingResult bindingResult,
                   Model model,
                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("message","Please fill in all necessary fields");
        addAttributes(model);
        return (game.getId()==0) ?
                   "admin/games/newGameForm" : "admin/games/editGameForm";
    }

    if(game.getTeams().size()>0 && 
       game.getTeams().get(0)!=null && 
       game.getTeams().get(1)!=null &&
              (game.getTeams().get(0).getId() ==
               game.getTeams().get(1).getId())) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Teams cannot be the same. Try again");
        addAttributes(model);
        return (game.getId()==0) ? 
             "admin/games/newGameForm" : "admin/games/editGameForm";
    }

    if(game.getDate()!=null && game.getDate().before(new Date())) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Date must be in the future. Try again");
        addAttributes(model);
        return (game.getId()==0) ? 
                 "admin/games/newGameForm" : "admin/games/editGameForm";
    }

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", 
       (game.getId()==0) ? 
                 "New game was created succesfully" : "Game was updated succesfully");
    gameService.save(game);
    return "redirect:/admin/games/page/1/date/asc";
}
```

To test this method, i wrote the following test:

```
@Test
public void saveNewGame() throws Exception{

    mockMvc.perform(post("/admin/game/save")
            .param("date", "01/10/2018")
            .param("teams", "1"))
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/admin/games/page/1/date/asc"))
            .andExpect(
               MockMvcResultMatchers.
               flash().
               attribute("message", "New game was created succesfully"));

    ArgumentCaptor<Game> boundGame = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Game.class);
    verify(gameService).save(boundGame.capture());

    Assert.assertEquals(DataLoader.parseDate("01/10/2018"), 
                        boundGame.getValue().getDate());
}
```

Spring automatically creates this Game object and maps the values which i add to the MockMvcBuilder as parameters with the fields of the game object. This all works fine with primitive data types and the Data object i used above (the String value is perfectly transformed into a Date object because i annotated the Date attribute with a pattern, see the code below of the Game bean:

```
@Entity
public class Game {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@NotNull
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();

private Integer scoreTeamA;

private Integer scoreTeamB;

@ManyToOne
private Location location;

@ManyToOne
private Competition competition;

@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date date;

public Game(){}

//getters and setters and more
}
```

But when a want to give a List of team objects, which is also attribute of the game objects, I get a BindingResultError which says:

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'game' on field 'teams': rejected value [1];
>   codes
>   [typeMismatch.game.teams,typeMismatch.teams,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [game.teams,teams]; arguments []; default message [teams]];
>   default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property
>   'teams'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'com.davidstranders.sportclub.model.Team' for property 'teams[0]': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Above i tried to set a teamId as value for the teams object because this is also what happens when a user selects a team when he creates a game object, see the template (uses Thymeleaf):

```
 <div th:class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('teams')}? 'has-error'">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">
            Teams <span class="required">*</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
           <div class="col-md-5">
                <select class="form-control" th:field="*{teams}">
                    <option value="">Select team</option>
                    <option th:each="team : ${teams}" 
                            th:value="${team.id}" 
                            th:text="${team.name}">teams
                    </option>
                </select>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('teams')}" 
                           th:errors="*{teams}"
                           th:class="help-block">Team Errors</span>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-1"><label>vs</label></div>
           <div class="col-md-5">
                <select class="form-control" th:field="*{teams}">
                    <option value="">Select team</option>
                    <option th:each="team : ${teams}" 
                            th:value="${team.id}" 
                            th:text="${team.name}">teams
                    </option>
                </select>
                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('teams')}" 
                      th:errors="*{teams}" 
                      th:class="help-block">Team Errors</span>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Have anyone any idea how to deal with this? I tried to give a List with teams as String, or team instances as String, but this didn't work.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Instead of `.param("teams", "1"))` try `.param("teams[0].id", "1"))`

Comment: it worked, thanks!